# Deploying Application with OpenSSL in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, deployment, ssl, openssl

I've developed an application for GNU/Linux that uses the OpenSSL library. This application is supposed to run in both Debian and Red Hat-based distributions.

What is the best strategy to ensure the user's system will have the OpenSSL library installed? Should I include a dependency on the .deb or .rpm for a specific version of the OpenSSL? How can I handle systems with older versions of OpenSSL, such as 0.9.8, and newer ones with 1.0.0? Or is it best to statically link it?

Thank you

Comment: Release your app as a RPM and/or Debian package. Both packagers enable you to specify dependencies on other packages.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I handle different versions of OpenSSL? I mean, Ubuntu 10.10 has a package called libssl0.9.8, which does not exist in newer versions. In Ubuntu 12.04, the package is called simply openssl. These are the type of conflicts I'm not sure how to handle.

Comment: Sorry, not a packaging expert. The Debian project maintains good doco: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses Debian packages (.deb), RedHat uses RPM. You will have to create two different spec files to build packages for these two distributions, at least.

When you dynamically link against different versions of the library, you should really build several versions of your executable as well. Usually, the .so API is only guaranteed to stay the same for a major version. I.e. 0.9.4 will be compatible to 0.9.9, but not 1.0.1.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I will follow the advice and create multiple packages.